# Array never gets defined before render() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm extremely new to React and I'm really having a hard time figuring out a lot of things. Right now I'm trying to fetch data from my database as the user loads my homepage. I do this with this async function:

```
    let result = await fetch("/api/init", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("kSuccess");
        return data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("kError:", error);
      });

    return result;
  }
```

Then I have an async componentDidMount() function to call setState when the promise actually returns data:

```
let myData = await this.initData().then(function (data) {
      return data;
    });
    this.setState({ values: myData });
```

And if I log it at this point, the this.state.values array exists and is what I want it to be.

But when I render in this function:

```
render() {

console.log("1, ", items);

return (
<div>
     <label {...getLabelProps}>Autocomplete test</label>
     <input {...getInputProps} />
           {console.log("2, ", items)}
             <ul>
                 {items.map(item => (
                 <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
                 ))}
             </ul>
</div>
);
}
```

That ul that is supposed to generate li for each item in the items is empty because it thinks items is empty. I'm not sure why, because that console.log statement #1 prints items normally, but #2 prints an empty array.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way/time to fetch data from my database in react? I'd love an easier way to do this.

Thanks

EDIT: I forgot to mention that items is declared as a global like `let items = [];`

and is defined in componentDidMount() as `items = this.state.values;`

Here is the full file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Downshift from "downshift";

let items = [];

class AC extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  async initData() {


    let result = await fetch("/api/init", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ values: data });
        console.log("kSuccess");
        return data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("kError:", error);
      });

    return result;
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let vals = await this.initData().then(function (data) {
      return data;
    });
    this.setState({ values: vals });
    
    items = this.state.values;

    console.log(items);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("1, ", items);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Hello </h1>
        <div>
          <Downshift>
            {({ getLabelProps, getInputProps }) => (
              <div>
                <label {...getLabelProps}>Autocomplete test</label>
                <input {...getInputProps} />
                {console.log("2, ", items)}
                <ul>
                  {items.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            )}
          </Downshift>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AC;
```

Comment: try to replace `items` with `this.state.values` inside of your render function

Comment: I get the error that "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". Also I'll edit the post but I fogot to mention that items is global and i didn't include the declaration/definition of it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting up the data in state `this.setState({ values: myData });` and recalling that in render function by using `items`, so try to replace the `items` with `this.state.items`.

Comment: I get the error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I will edit the post, but items is global and is defined in the componentDidMount() function like so: `items = this.state.values;`

Comment: Global variables are a common pitfall many developers fall into. You assign to your variable a first state and this value will never change afterward. Global variables are declared outside of a function for accessibility throughout the program, while local variables are stored within a function.
remove global variable and use state instead and declare this below render and above return function
`const {values} = this.state;`
and use `values.map`

Comment: But even when I use state variables as you suggested, I get this error: "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" and the local state variable which I am setting early on is somehow undefined before I render the component. What should I do?

Comment: can you put the whole file here, there must be missing piece of code which is not here in question.

Comment: The error occur mainly becuase the array isnt found. or you are not setting up the data correctly, Just check if you have mapped to the correct array. Check the array name or declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I just decided to use a state variable instead of a global variable. So I initialized state in my constructor as `this.state = {items: []};` and changed all the places that used the items array to `this.state.items` and that worked.

Comment: Great   please upvote if you find any of my answer useful.